# Query based on the date range in BigQuery returns error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am doing the query with a condition based on the date range for about a week. My simple code is:

```
select *
from table
where DATE(Request_Timestamp) >  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

However the query throws error:

```
No matching signature for operator > for argument types: DATE, TIMESTAMP. Supported signatures: ANY > ANY at [3:7]
```

The expected result is a table within a week from this current date (today). The timestamp is:

```
2020-05-10 06:14:25.276 UTC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```sql
select *
from table
where TIMESTAMP(DATE(Request_Timestamp)) >  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

- `DATE()` truncates to a date.
- Then `TIMESTAMP()` makes it a timestamp again, allowing the desired comparison.

[image]